# Omitting the href attribute in an a element?

Tags: javascript, html

So many times writing html code along with javascript, I create `<a>` elements.

My question is, can I ignore the href attribute? as I rather add an ID attribute and handle the click there.

Most of the time when I do that, its not to go to a different page, but more to perform a ajax call of some sort.

I hate having the # in the url, it just looks ugly.

Should I rather use a different element, i.e. a `<span>` and just modify it with a class to look like link?

Thanx
J

Comment: Well if it's not a link then yes, use another more semantic tag. If it's a link then fill the href with `#` or url

Comment: I've seen `javascript:void(0)` used instead of the `#`

Comment: lol **musa** I guess OP wouldn't find that any prettier than `#`

Comment: @elclanrs with `#` a # is added to the url in the address bar when you click the link but with `javascript:void(0)` nothing is added

Comment: **@musa** You're right...but I usually do this `$('a.nourl').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault() })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a link without a `href`, it's not a link, it's probably a **button**, and you should be using one, instead of a link.

**[Button VS. Link - User Experience.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/5493)**

Answer (score 2):

**if you dont want use any value in href want**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"​ >link</a>
```

**if dont want to add href but want pointer style of cursor**

```
<a style="cursor:pointer">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It's not necessary to use `href` attribute if the purpose is to achieve only click event and not `link` to some page or tab.

You can style the `a` tag with CSS by some `classname` or directly `a{ cursor: pointer; color: blue;}`

But you can not style `a` element using `a:link` if the `href` attribute is not assigned

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need an href with an `a` tag. It basically distinguishes it from the other and makes it look clickable. You can use `a` or any other element for that matter with an onclick for your purpose.

```
<a class="lookClickable" onclick="doSomething()">Click Me</a>
```

(the above could be anything other than `a` too like `span`, `div` etc.

Comment: It doesn't just make it *look* clickable, it makes it focusable, so it can be navigated to with all the systems that allow selection of elements other then with a pointing device (mouse, trackball, etc).